# Is solr LFU cache implemented properly?

Tags: caching, solr, solr5

When the `solr` LFU cache was introduced, it was a really crappy implementation, but this was long back. I wanted to know does anyone have any idea if there have been any improvements to that implementation? and can I use it now?

Comment: What version of the solr are you talking about? Latest version is 5.2.x. Can you point out what flaws it had that time.

Comment: It used to work really slow in solr 3.6. I wanted to know whether it has been improved in the later solr releases?

Comment: Please check [this](http://www.programering.com/a/MjMzQDNwATg.html). it seems to provide some details about solr LFU cache. You might want to consider FastLRU cache for faster reads and slower write, if your requirement suits it.